# Standard represention of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am wondering how to extract the standard representation from the permutation representation? I want to obtain the permutation rep matrices $\Gamma((1,2)), \Gamma((1,3))$ and $\Gamma((1,3,2))$ in the standard representation in a basis where $\underline{e}_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} (1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$, $\underline{e}_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(0,1,-1)$ and $\underline{e}_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$

I can obtain the corresponding transformation matrix and then compute $\Gamma' = T^{\dagger}\Gamma T = T^T \Gamma T$, but when I have this $\Gamma'$ I don't know how to then extract the standard representation as per the question requirements.

Many thanks.

Comment: what is *"the standard representation"* for you?

Comment: I am told that the standard representation in the basis $\left\{e_1, e_2 \right\}$ for $\Gamma((1,2))$ is $$\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -1&\sqrt{3}\\..&..\end{pmatrix}$$ I inferred that entry $(22)$ is $1$ by using $\chi(\Gamma_{perm}) = \chi (\Gamma_{triv}) + (\chi(\Gamma_{stand}))$ and therefore $(21)$ is also $\sqrt{3}$ by orthogonality of the rows.  But the above matrix was given as a hint in the question, how are they actually constructed?

Comment: here [ http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3 ] you'll find something ad hoc

Comment: precisely [ http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3#Representation_table ]

Comment: Yes, I noticed that link previously but I was wondering how they are actually obtained. As in the OP, (I think) I have found the permutation representation in the $\left\{e_i\right\}$ basis, now I need to somehow extract the standard rep.  Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't calculate the exact result but let me give you some ingredients:

You should know how to transform a matrix to another via a change of basis. This way we can work with a preferred one. Mine is the standard basis. Since you used $e_i$ already lets call them $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

You hopefully know how the permutation matrices that you called $\Gamma((1,2)),\dots$ look like. (e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$)

Now the part that you probably had trouble with. The standard representation lives on the vector space usually defined by $\mathbb C^3/ \langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ (assuming you work over $\mathbb C$ although every field would work here). This vector space is two-dimensional and one can see that the images of $v_1$ and $v_2$ are again form a basis. Let us call them $\bar v_1, \bar v_2$.

Now we only need to know what happens on these two vectors. Note that the image of $v_1+v_2+v_3$ is zero, so whenever we get $\bar v_3$ we replace it by $-\bar v_1-\bar v_2$.

Example: $\Gamma((1,2,3))$

$v_1$ is sent to $v_2$ and $v_2$ is sent to $v_3$, hence $\bar v_1$ gets sent to $\bar v_2$ and $\bar v_2$ gets sent to $\bar v_3 = -\bar v_1-\bar v_2$. Thus the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Now you only have to work out what the images $\bar e_1, \bar e_2$ of $e_1,e_2$ are in terms of $\bar v_1, \bar v_2$ and do the base change.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you explain though why the standard representation is defined on $\mathbb{C}$ complement the vector $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$?

Comment: I guess that is a different question but let me say the following:
We know that $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb C^3$ by permuting the standard basis vectors. So it only permutes the entries of a vector. If all entries are the same, the vector stays fixed. In particular $\langle (1,1,1)\rangle$ is an $S_3$-subrepresentation. Therefore we can consider the quotient vector space also as $S_3$-representation.

Comment: Because of Maschke we can also find a subrepresentation of the permutation representation that is isomorphic to the standard representation. This would be $\{(x,y,z)\mid x+y+z =0\}$.